# nftables anonymous map for ipv6 dnat

Tags: routing, ipv6, nat, nftables

When creating a dnat rule, you can specify the following command:

```
nft 'add rule ip  twilight prerouting ip  daddr 1.2.3.0/24 dnat ip  prefix to ip  daddr map { 1.2.3.0/24 : 2.3.4.0/24 }'
```

And then get dnat that maps addresses like `1.2.3.4 -> 2.3.4.4`. This command runs as expected with `nftables v1.0.4 (Lester Gooch #3)`, and according to the answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1017659).

If I try to do the same with ipv6, using the following commands:

```
nft 'add rule ip6 twilight prerouting ip6 daddr aa:bb:cc:dd::/64 dnat ip6 prefix to ip6 daddr map { [aa:bb:cc:dd::]/64 : [bb:cc:dd:ee::]/64 }'
nft 'add rule ip6 twilight prerouting ip6 daddr aa:bb:cc:dd::/64 dnat ip6 prefix to ip6 daddr map { aa:bb:cc:dd::/64 : bb:cc:dd:ee::/64 }'
nft 'add rule ip6 twilight prerouting ip6 daddr aa:bb:cc:dd::/64 dnat ip6 prefix to ip6 daddr map { "aa:bb:cc:dd::/64" : "bb:cc:dd:ee::/64" }'
```

Then, I get the following error messages:

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected newline
add rule ip6 twilight prerouting ip6 daddr aa:bb:cc:dd::/64 dnat ip6 prefix to ip6 daddr map { [aa:bb:cc:dd::]/64 : [bb:cc:dd:ee::]/64 }
                                                                                                                                        ^
Error: syntax error, unexpected newline
add rule ip6 twilight prerouting ip6 daddr aa:bb:cc:dd::/64 dnat ip6 prefix to ip6 daddr map { aa:bb:cc:dd::/64 : bb:cc:dd:ee::/64 }
                                                                                                                                    ^
Error: syntax error, unexpected newline
add rule ip6 twilight prerouting ip6 daddr aa:bb:cc:dd::/64 dnat ip6 prefix to ip6 daddr map { "aa:bb:cc:dd::/64" : "bb:cc:dd:ee::/64" }
                                                                                                                                        ^
```

Is there a way that I can make anonymous ipv6 maps in nftables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: You need at least nftables version >= 1.0.5.

---

In [version 1.0.5](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/nftables/files/changes-nftables-1.0.5.txt):

> ```
>       scanner: allow prefix in ip6 scope
> ```

Which matches [this commit](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?h=v1.0.5&id=45c097c60b3a5a2151fad976a0006048afce869a):

> scanner: allow prefix in ip6 scope
>
> 'ip6 prefix' is valid syntax, so make sure scanner recognizes it also
> in ip6 context.
>
> Also add test case.

[...]

> ```
> diff --git a/tests/shell/testcases/sets/0046netmap_0 b/tests/shell/testcases/sets/0046netmap_0
> index 2804a4a2..60bda401 100755
> --- a/tests/shell/testcases/sets/0046netmap_0
> +++ b/tests/shell/testcases/sets/0046netmap_0
> @@ -8,6 +8,12 @@ EXPECTED="table ip x {
>                            10.141.13.0/24 : 192.168.4.0/24 > }
>              }
>       }
> +     table ip6 x {
> +            chain y {
> +                    type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
> +                    snat ip6 prefix to ip6 saddr map { 2001:db8:1111::/64 : 2001:db8:2222::/64 }
> +            }
> +     }
>  "
>  
>  set -e
> ```

The corresponding regression test is similar to OP's attempt. OP's syntax tested ok here with nftables 1.0.7.

Comment: I didn't manage to use a workaround (that would use raw payload mangling: conntrack wouldn't catch the change contrary to my expectaction and only the first packet of a flow was NAT-ed in the attempt).

Comment: Tested and working against nftables 1.0.7, thank you very much!